# Given $n \ge 3$ points in the plane, prove that some three of them form an angle less than or equal to $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Given $n \ge 3$ points in the plane, prove that some three of them form an angle less than or equal to $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

The convex hull of the polygon formed by the $n$ points has an interior angle at most $\frac{\pi(n-2)}{n}$. Is there some way to use this fact to get a bound for the angle formed by some $3$ of the points? This problem was on a book in a chapter related to ordered sets so I suppose that some kind of ordering would be in place here.

Comment: See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2347666p18994160) (found with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%20%5Cge%203%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)).